# Wedge product of vector and tensor

Tags: exterior-algebra

As near as I can figure it:

(a⊗b)∧c = a⊗b⊗c - a⊗c⊗b + c⊗a⊗b

But I'm not sure if thats right.

a, b, and c are vectors.

I know that a∧b = a⊗b - b⊗a which is a bivector.

The equation I am most interested in is a∧b∧c = (a⊗b - b⊗a)∧c which is evidently a trivector and a rank 3 tensor. I know that the wedge product distributes over addition.

Comment: I'm not sure I even know what this means.

Comment: Outer product and wedge product

Comment: Are there parentheses around one pair? I can see making sense of $a\otimes(b\wedge c)$, but not the other way. Indeed, as you now edited, $b\wedge c = b\otimes c- c\otimes b$, and so $a\otimes(b\wedge c) = a\otimes b\otimes c - a\otimes c\otimes b$ makes perfectly good sense.

Comment: The equation I am most interested in is a∧b∧c =  (a⊗b - b⊗a)∧c which is evidently a trivector and a rank 3 tensor. I know that the wedge product distributes over addition.

Comment: Yes, that one makes sense. But the wedge product is defined by total skew-symmetrization of the tensor.

Comment: I thought wedge product is only defined for two alternating tensors. An arbitrary tensor $a\otimes b$ is seldom alternating.

Comment: Correct, and that's why I complained at the outset. You have to totally skew-symmetrize for wedge product to make sense.

Comment: a⊗b - b⊗a would be skew symmetric

Comment: Wedge product is only defined between vectors in the same vector space. If $a,b,c$ are vectors in $V$, then $a \wedge b = a \otimes b - b \otimes a \in \bigwedge^2 V \subseteq V \otimes V$, but $c \in V$.

Comment: Trivectors are well known geometric objects.